# Teams Webhook gives ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is the webhook connections broken in Microsoft Teams or how do we solve the following issue?

When applying the [Microsoft Teams Get Started documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-connectors) we get the following response in Postman.

> "System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

We have set up a webhook in Teams and use it to post Application Insights messages to a Logic App where one of the actions is the webhook to Teams. Everything went fine until now (7/21 and 7/22, 2019) when we saw in Azure the same exception as a response on status 200. To figure this all out we went back to basic and tried to execute the Get Started documentation. The same exception was thrown.

Code that we used was all from the documentation.

[image: Postman headers plus result]

[image: Postman body plus result]

Comment: I tried following the steps you have mentioned but I could not repro the issue. Webhooks work as expected for me. Could you please share the webhookUrl used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day or two the exception wasn't returned anymore after NO modifications to the logic app or payload to the Teams webhook. Everything works fine now.

For future use we added an action to the Logic App to read out the webhook's response to determine futher actions, like sending an e-mail if webhook failed.

Comment: The same issue happens now :)